# Casting inner objects in java - unchecked exception

Tags: java, arrays, inner-classes

I'm having a problem with inner classes. I build an object (let's say a train) with an inner class representing states (let's say the stops of the train).

I'm trying to run this code:

```
private void CustomObjectBuilder (String [] origin) {

  final int array_dim = origin.length;

  InnerCustomObject[] tmp_bin = new InnerCustomObject[array_dim];

  for (int ii = 0; ii < array_dim; ii++) {

   String debug = extractData(origin[ii]);


   tmp_bin[ii].setData(debug);



  }




 }
```

It compiles just just fine but at runtime I get a null object exception.

What am I doing wrong?

Here you can finde the original code:

```
public class CustomObject {



    InnerCustomObject [] stops;

    public class InnerCustomObject {

        String name, station, schedTime, depTime, schedRail, depRail;

        public void setData (String origin) {

            this.station = origin;
        }

    }
}
```

Edit: I solved by calling

```
 CustomObject.InnerCustomObject ico = new CustomObject(). new InnerCustomObject();
```

why it needs to be so verbose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the most immediate thing I notice is you don't populate `tmp_bin[]` with any objects after you declare it. When you first create an array, all it contains are `null`s.

So when you do this in your loop:

```
tmp_bin[ii].setData(debug);
```

There is nothing to invoke `setData()` on, resulting in the exception.

Re edit: you can just do

```
InnerCustomObject ico = this.new InnerCustomObject();
```

since you're creating them within your outer `CustomObject` class's `CustomObjectBuilder()` instance method.

Comment: I thought that, but if I add   tmp_bin[ii] = new InnerCustomObject();   it doesn't compile... how do I fix this?

Comment: You'd have to show more code. What does your `InnerCustomObject` class look like? What error does the compiler give?

Comment: I get a null pointer exception when I try to access the first element of the array...

Comment: But NullPointerExceptions are runtime errors, not compile-time errors. I'm asking about what error the compiler gives when you try to compile with `tmp_bin[ii] = new InnerCustomObject();` and it fails.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't show anything, just a red X with no info. I solved by doing CustomObject.InnerCustomObject ico = new CustomObject(). new InnerCustomObject(); .... why it need to be so verbose?

Answer (score 1):

```
InnerCustomObject[] tmp_bin = new InnerCustomObject[array_dim];
```

declares an array of array_dim elements but all are null. Then this

```
tmp_bin[ii].setData(debug);
```

won't work.

No problem with inner classes only with an object that is null (=NPE) so you cannot call the method setData().

Answer (score 1):

In your loop you have to create new instance of InnerCustomObject. By new InnerCustomObject[size] you do not create new instances.